# apt-get behind proxy. Special characters in username and password

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, apt-get

I would like to set apt-get to use a proxy on my ubuntu box. I have successfully configured synaptic to use a proxy, so I can install packages, but I would like to be able to use the command line.

My work proxy requires both a username and password, both of which have special characters in them.

In my `.bashrc` I have

```sh
export http_proxy="http://user@company:P@$$1234@10.20.30.40:80/"
```

however, this doesn't work.

I've also tried escaping the special characters but that doesn't seem to work either:

```sh
export http_proxy="http://user\@company:P\@\$\$1234@10.20.30.40:80/"
```

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/60217/apt-get-update-with-an-in-password-error ?

Comment: I did see that post, however, escaping the special characters doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seemed to be a combination of 2 things. I needed to use escape codes for the special characters and I needed to add entries to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. (Supposedly, exporting the _proxy environment variables should make apt-get work, but I did not have that luck.)

`/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated 1;
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user%40company:P%40%24%241234@10.20.30.40:80/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user%40company:P%40%24%241234@10.20.30.40:80/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user%40company:P%40%24%241234@10.20.30.40:80/";
```

`.bashrc`:

```
export http_proxy="http://user%40company:P%40%24%241234@10.20.30.40:80/";
export ftp_proxy="ftp://user%40company:P%40%24%241234@10.20.30.40:80/";
export https_proxy="https://user%40company:P%40%24%241234@10.20.30.40:80/";
```

Comment: URL encoding may be found here:  
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: What if ```@``` is followed by numbers? example ````Pass@40Word```.

Answer (score 1):

**Even more simple and Reliable!**

**General Syntax:**

```
sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_url/_proxyip>:<port>/

wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://<website_url>
```

**Example:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://username:password-123@proxy.example.com:6050/

wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://google.com
```

**{http,https,ftp}_proxy**   -> http, https, ftp urls. Seperated by comma.

**--timeout=5**  -> Connection to keep alive in seconds.

**-no-check-certificate**  -> Ignore SSL / Certificate Verification.

**--spider**  -> If you want to test the connectivity without downloading the file.

**Notes:**

**Online Converter:**

Replace special characters with its equivalent hexadecimal unicode. 
For a list of unicodes refer the website [https://unicode-table.com](http://unicodelookup.com) (or) [http://unicodelookup.com](https://unicode-table.com)

**Local Converter using Python:**

**Reference:** conversion of password "p@s#w:E" to unicode will be as follows,

```
@ = %40
$ = %24
# = %23
: = %3A
p@s#w:E = p%40s%23w%3AE
```

**Input:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# python -c "import sys, urllib as enc; print enc.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "p@s#w:E"
```

**Output:**

```
p%40s%23w%3AE
```